# Can't pry off sliding shower door frame

Tags: shower, bathtub, frame

I'm removing a sliding shower door frame (tub-mounted) and had no problem getting the top and sides off. Then I started on the bottom portion attached to the tub. Cut through the caulk and went as deep as I could (not very) with a blade. The bottom frame is attached very tight... couldn't get a skinny pry bar or anything else into the crack. Tried yanking and pulling/pushing - didn't budge. No idea how it was attached! 
I was thinking about using a hacksaw on multiple smaller sections, which might give me a better chance of success of pulling off pieces. Can anyone offer any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Try grabbing it at one end with a locking plier and twisting. By concentrating the force it should tear loose.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a hacksaw blade, it will likely scratch the finish. Try to pass a length of dental floss under the end. Wrap the floss ends around screwdriver handles. Use a sawing motion to cut through the caulk or tape under the frame. Use a plastic scraper or something like alcohol or GOOF-OFF to clean the residue.